# How can I remove 'duplicate' method names from exception stacktrace?

Tags: c#

I would like to show only show part of the full exception and stacktrace.
I am currently calling ex.ToString() on the exception but I notice there are "duplicate" stacktrace entries.

The only thing I can think of is to parse the string for duplicate strings ignoring the line #.  I guess I will have to figure out a regex pattern.

E.g.: in the stacktrace there is "ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpTableRecord(..." listed twice but with different line #'s.

I use the try catch block in almost every single c# 4.0 method I write.

```
try
catch (Exception)
{
  throw;
}
```

And then when I want to raise a custom error I do this

```
try 
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw new Exception("my custom message", ex);
}
```

Then at the root level of code I basically show and/or log the error like so:

```
try 
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Exception found: " + ex.ToString();
}
```

However the stacktrace can look like this:

```
Error was logged: Error in ProcessExp() method.
Exception found: System.Exception: Error found in Database: C:\MyDatabase.mdb
 ---> System.Exception: Error found in Table: MyTable
 ---> System.Exception: Error found in TableID: 1
 ---> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Could not find output table 'testtable'.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at MiscOleDbFns.Querys.RunExecuteScaler(OleDbConnection Conn, String QueryString, Object[] ParamValues) in C:\Document Files\DotNet common libraries\src 4.0\misclibrary_src\source\MiscOleDbFns.cs:line 247
   at MiscOleDbFns.Querys.RunExecuteScalerAndGetAutoNumFromQuery(OleDbConnection Conn, String QueryString, Object[] ParamValues) in C:\Document Files\DotNet common libraries\src 4.0\misclibrary_src\source\MiscOleDbFns.cs:line 271
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.InsertExpSummaryFilesRec(OleDbConnection Conn, Boolean LogFile, RcdExpSummaryFiles Rcd) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 622
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.FindFileInList(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, Boolean isLogFile, Boolean isCopyFile, Boolean isDeleteFile, RcdExpSummaryFiles recExpSummaryFiles, Dictionary`2 myList) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 1216
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpTableRecordSusFiles(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, OleDbDataReader Read, RcdSchemaFlds recSchemaFlds, RcdExpSummary recExpSummary, String& tct) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 1257
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpTableRecord(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, OleDbDataReader Read, RcdSchemaFlds recSchemaFlds, RcdExpSummary recExpSummary) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 965
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpTableRecord(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, OleDbDataReader Read, RcdSchemaFlds recSchemaFlds, RcdExpSummary recExpSummary) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 982
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpDatabaseTable(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, OleDbConnection ConnExpDb, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, String mdbPath, String sTable, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 242
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpDatabaseTable(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, OleDbConnection ConnExpDb, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, String mdbPath, String sTable, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 250
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpDatabase(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String mdbPath, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 161
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpDatabase(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String mdbPath, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 174
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExp(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 74
```

Whereas I would like the error message to not have any duplicate messages; more like this:

```
Error was logged: Error in ProcessExp() method.
Exception found: System.Exception: Error found in Database: C:\MyDatabase.mdb
 ---> System.Exception: Error found in Table: MyTable
 ---> System.Exception: Error found in TableID: 1
 ---> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Could not find output table 'testtable'.

at MiscOleDbFns.Querys.RunExecuteScaler(OleDbConnection Conn, String QueryString, Object[] ParamValues) in C:\Document Files\DotNet common libraries\src 4.0\misclibrary_src\source\MiscOleDbFns.cs:line 247
   at MiscOleDbFns.Querys.RunExecuteScalerAndGetAutoNumFromQuery(OleDbConnection Conn, String QueryString, Object[] ParamValues) in C:\Document Files\DotNet common libraries\src 4.0\misclibrary_src\source\MiscOleDbFns.cs:line 271
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.InsertExpSummaryFilesRec(OleDbConnection Conn, Boolean LogFile, RcdExpSummaryFiles Rcd) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 622
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.FindFileInList(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, Boolean isLogFile, Boolean isCopyFile, Boolean isDeleteFile, RcdExpSummaryFiles recExpSummaryFiles, Dictionary`2 myList) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 1216
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpTableRecordSusFiles(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, OleDbDataReader Read, RcdSchemaFlds recSchemaFlds, RcdExpSummary recExpSummary, String& tct) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 1257
   at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpTableRecord(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, OleDbDataReader Read, RcdSchemaFlds recSchemaFlds, RcdExpSummary recExpSummary) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 965
at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpDatabaseTable(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, OleDbConnection ConnExpDb, String sCopyToDBFolderExp, String mdbPath, String sTable, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 242
at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExpDatabase(OleDbConnection conSystemDB, String mdbPath, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 161
at ProcessTeleformFiles.ProcessExp(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs workerEvents) in C:\Document Files\Projects and notes\VS 2010\Projects\OrganizeTeleformFiles\source\OrganizeTeleformFiles\ProcessFiles.cs:line 74
```

UPDATE:
So way back when, I did remove all the try catches in my code.  The only situation I modify the stacktrace now is in one place where I give a more user-friendly simplified output to a user. Internally I always log the full stack.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: What are you trying to do? These are not 'duplicate'.  They are the current frames on the stack.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I figure the message string will be shorter and more readable and thus useful.

Comment: And why would you want to make it shorter? If it's shorter, it will be incomplete, which will make it harder to find the cause of the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra rows in the stack trace are not "duplicates", they indicate the flow of execution - in this case where the exception was caught and rethrown.  If you remove them then you are removing valuable information about what happened which is some day going to cause yourself a world of hurt when you are trying to debug an error and can't work out what happened.

The solution is simple - **don't wrap each method in a try-catch block**.  It complicates stack traces (as you have seen), incurs a performance penalty every time the exception is caught and re-thrown and makes it very difficult to catch specific exception types.

There is absolutely no advantage to catching and rethrowing exceptions in each method - just catch it when you can do something useful with it which in your case is at the "root level" where you handle it by showing an error message.

Comment: @user: this can't be emphasized enough. You are ruining your application apparently because you think you need try/catch around every method. That is precisely the wrong thing to do and will make your troubleshooting life a nightmare. You should almost never surround code with try/catch.

Comment: I do need to use try catch to help me keep track exactly where an error is as I loop through Database records (Databasename, tablename, record id)  and so I use the throw new Exception( "table name xxx", ex) theory.
  I will remove the empty try catches and see how that works.  Now I guess I'll have to come up with some creative regex to remove the try catch blocks from many many methods.

Comment: @user610064 Catching and then wrapping / rethrowing an exception in order to add additional detail (such as the name of items being processed in a loop) is fine and common practice, its catching and wrapping exceptions in all the places where you have no additional information which is causing you problems

Comment: If I use regex: \}\n+:b+catch.*\n+:b+\{\n+:b+throw;\n+:b+\}
It will find the catch part (below) of the block but then I have to manually remove the top try and open brace.... hmmm:

      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        throw;
      }

Answer (score 1):

If you remove entries from the stacktrace it isn't a stacktrace any more! It shows exactly which function were called and when a function calls itself then this is a notable information!